# access outside array variable inside class

Tags: php, scope

I have an array. but I don't know how to access it inside a class.

below is my sample code.

```
<?php

$value[0]=11;
$value[1]=22;
$value[2]=33;

class test {
    var $code1,$code2,$code3;

    function __construct() {
            $this->$code1 = $value[0];
            $this->$code2 = $value[1];
            $this->$code3 = $value[2];
            echo $code1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

And you can do any one of the following:

**Pass the value into the constructor as a parameter (recommended option)**

```
<?php

$value[0]=11;
$value[1]=22;
$value[2]=33;

class test {
    var $code1,$code2,$code3;

    function __construct($value) {
            $this->code1 = $value[0];
            $this->code2 = $value[1];
            $this->code3 = $value[2];
            echo $this->code1;
        }

}

$obj = new test($value);

?>
```

**Use the `$GLOBALS` array** ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php))

```
<?php

$value[0]=11;
$value[1]=22;
$value[2]=33;

class test {
    var $code1,$code2,$code3;

    function __construct() {
            $this->code1 = $GLOBALS['value'][0];
            $this->code2 = $GLOBALS['value'][1];
            $this->code3 = $GLOBALS['value'][2];
            echo $this->code1;
        }

}

$obj = new test;

?>
```

**Use the `global` keyword** ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global))

```
<?php

$value[0]=11;
$value[1]=22;
$value[2]=33;

class test {
    var $code1,$code2,$code3;

    function __construct() {
            global $value;
            $this->code1 = $value[0];
            $this->code2 = $value[1];
            $this->code3 = $value[2];
            echo $this->code1;
        }

}

$obj = new test;

?>
```

---

**NOTES**

I have corrected a couple of errors above.

You should use `$this->code1` instead of `$this->$code1`. The second version is valid syntactically, but means something else. Consider the following example:

```
 class myClass {

   public $myVar = "My Var";
   public $anotherVar = "Another Var";

   function __construct () {

     // creates a local variable to the constructor, called $myVar
     // does NOT overwrite the value defined above for the object property
     $myVar = "anotherVar";

     echo $myVar; // echoes 'anotherVar'
     echo $this->myVar; // echoes 'My Var'
     echo $this->$myVar; // echoes 'Another Var'

   }

 }
```

Also, the above example illustrates the reason why you should use `echo $this->code1;` and not simply `echo $code1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
class test { 
    private $code1,$code2,$code3;

    function __construct($value) {
        $this->code1 = $value[0];
        $this->code2 = $value[1];
        $this->code3 = $value[2];
        echo $this->code1;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
$test = new Test($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class test
{
    var $code1,$code2,$code3;

    function __construct($input)
    {
        $this->code1 = $input[0];
        $this->code2 = $input[1];
        $this->code3 = $input[2];
    }
}

[...]

$value[0]=11;
$value[1]=22;
$value[2]=33;

$test = new test($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables aren't visible inside functions, unless you use the `global` keyword.  e.g.:

```
// Global variable
$x = 5;

// Won't affect the global
function foo()
{
    $x = 3;
}

// Will affect the global
function bar()
{
    global $x;
    $x = 2;
}
```

**Note**

However, in general, it's not a good idea to use global variables like this.  It introduces dependencies, and makes your code harder to test and to debug.  I suggest you pass the variable in as an argument to your constructor.

Comment: IMHO, `global` really isn't something you should be advertising.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Indeed; I've explicitly explained that this is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oli, Dave, Alfwed, CodeCaster for your help. So what i learnt from this is I should pass the values to avoid unnecessary dependencies and use $this->var instead of $this->$var to avoid overwriting. This is great. Thank u all again

Comment: let's say we have `$config` variable that stores variables from config.php file? what should we do now? pass it for every constructer  & make server ram usage great?